# how do I make this css loader's position go down?

Tags: html, css

I had a question I think yesterday and they solved my problem but now I have a new problem :/ the problem is that I need to position of the css loader to go down because when I add it it's like right under the text I have above of it like for example this is the code:

```
<!-- Only An Example Not My Full Code -->
<center><h1>Example</h1></center>
<div id="squaresWaveG">
<div id="squaresWaveG_1" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_2" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_3" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_4" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_5" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_6" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_7" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_8" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
</div>
```

so when I do that code then the css loader is right under the text and I don't want that I want it to be like close to the bottom of the page but I don't know how to make it go down, here's my full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4Ljayw2f/1/

```css
#squaresWaveG{
position:relative;
width:240px;
height:29px;
margin:0 auto;
}

.squaresWaveG{
position:absolute;
top:0;
background-color:#000000;
width:29px;
height:29px;
-moz-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-moz-animation-duration:3.3s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-direction:linear;
-webkit-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-webkit-animation-duration:3.3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction:linear;
-ms-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-ms-animation-duration:3.3s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-ms-animation-direction:linear;
-o-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-o-animation-duration:3.3s;
-o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-direction:linear;
animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
animation-duration:3.3s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-direction:linear;
}

#squaresWaveG_1{
left:0;
-moz-animation-delay:1.32s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.32s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.32s;
-o-animation-delay:1.32s;
animation-delay:1.32s;
}

#squaresWaveG_2{
left:30px;
-moz-animation-delay:1.65s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.65s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.65s;
-o-animation-delay:1.65s;
animation-delay:1.65s;
}

#squaresWaveG_3{
left:60px;
-moz-animation-delay:1.98s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.98s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.98s;
-o-animation-delay:1.98s;
animation-delay:1.98s;
}

#squaresWaveG_4{
left:90px;
-moz-animation-delay:2.31s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2.31s;
-ms-animation-delay:2.31s;
-o-animation-delay:2.31s;
animation-delay:2.31s;
}

#squaresWaveG_5{
left:120px;
-moz-animation-delay:2.64s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2.64s;
-ms-animation-delay:2.64s;
-o-animation-delay:2.64s;
animation-delay:2.64s;
}

#squaresWaveG_6{
left:150px;
-moz-animation-delay:2.97s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2.97s;
-ms-animation-delay:2.97s;
-o-animation-delay:2.97s;
animation-delay:2.97s;
}

#squaresWaveG_7{
left:180px;
-moz-animation-delay:3.3s;
-webkit-animation-delay:3.3s;
-ms-animation-delay:3.3s;
-o-animation-delay:3.3s;
animation-delay:3.3s;
}

#squaresWaveG_8{
left:210px;
-moz-animation-delay:3.63s;
-webkit-animation-delay:3.63s;
-ms-animation-delay:3.63s;
-o-animation-delay:3.63s;
animation-delay:3.63s;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-o-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}
```

```html
<div id="squaresWaveG">
<div id="squaresWaveG_1" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_2" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_3" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_4" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_5" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_6" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_7" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_8" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine how far down the page you want the images and add the

top: 300px;

to your css.

```
#squaresWaveG{
position:relative;
top: 200px;
width:240px;
height:29px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your position to `absolute` and center it.

```
#squaresWaveG{
position:absolute;
width:240px;
height:29px;
margin:0 auto;
bottom: 3em;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -120px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jeevkhz3/)

Oh, and PS, what's the point of the separate ID and Class? Not sure the reason at first glance but whatever is clever. :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test-div{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;

}
#squaresWaveG{
position:absolute;
bottom: 10px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -120px;
width:240px;
height:29px;

}

.squaresWaveG{
position:absolute;
top:0;
background-color:#000000;
width:29px;
height:29px;
-moz-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-moz-animation-duration:3.3s;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-direction:linear;
-webkit-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-webkit-animation-duration:3.3s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-webkit-animation-direction:linear;
-ms-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-ms-animation-duration:3.3s;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-ms-animation-direction:linear;
-o-animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
-o-animation-duration:3.3s;
-o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-o-animation-direction:linear;
animation-name:bounce_squaresWaveG;
animation-duration:3.3s;
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
animation-direction:linear;
}

#squaresWaveG_1{
left:0;
-moz-animation-delay:1.32s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.32s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.32s;
-o-animation-delay:1.32s;
animation-delay:1.32s;
}

#squaresWaveG_2{
left:30px;
-moz-animation-delay:1.65s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.65s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.65s;
-o-animation-delay:1.65s;
animation-delay:1.65s;
}

#squaresWaveG_3{
left:60px;
-moz-animation-delay:1.98s;
-webkit-animation-delay:1.98s;
-ms-animation-delay:1.98s;
-o-animation-delay:1.98s;
animation-delay:1.98s;
}

#squaresWaveG_4{
left:90px;
-moz-animation-delay:2.31s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2.31s;
-ms-animation-delay:2.31s;
-o-animation-delay:2.31s;
animation-delay:2.31s;
}

#squaresWaveG_5{
left:120px;
-moz-animation-delay:2.64s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2.64s;
-ms-animation-delay:2.64s;
-o-animation-delay:2.64s;
animation-delay:2.64s;
}

#squaresWaveG_6{
left:150px;
-moz-animation-delay:2.97s;
-webkit-animation-delay:2.97s;
-ms-animation-delay:2.97s;
-o-animation-delay:2.97s;
animation-delay:2.97s;
}

#squaresWaveG_7{
left:180px;
-moz-animation-delay:3.3s;
-webkit-animation-delay:3.3s;
-ms-animation-delay:3.3s;
-o-animation-delay:3.3s;
animation-delay:3.3s;
}

#squaresWaveG_8{
left:210px;
-moz-animation-delay:3.63s;
-webkit-animation-delay:3.63s;
-ms-animation-delay:3.63s;
-o-animation-delay:3.63s;
animation-delay:3.63s;
}

@-moz-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-ms-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@-o-keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}

@keyframes bounce_squaresWaveG{
0%{
background-color:#000000;
}

100%{
background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="test-div">
<div id="squaresWaveG">
<div id="squaresWaveG_1" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_2" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_3" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_4" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_5" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_6" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_7" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
<div id="squaresWaveG_8" class="squaresWaveG">
</div>
</div>
</div> //test dive ends
```

check the fiddle i have updated https://jsfiddle.net/4Ljayw2f/2/